# Android project building fails after adding Geotools implementation

Tags: geotools

I am starting to use Geotools in my Android app. The thing is that after adding implenentation to gradle:

```
implementation 'org.geotools:gt-main:28.0'
```

and resources

```
 maven {
            url "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/"
        }
```

when I tried to build project I get:

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'plugin.xml' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\lukas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.eclipse.emf\org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi\2.15.0\9aa1a584be1df1eb0ef8fae7123784af6e51f47a\org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.15.0.jar
      - C:\Users\lukas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.eclipse.emf\org.eclipse.emf.ecore\2.15.0\ccfc09c8b6a0d4fadde09216d8a07678d38998de\org.eclipse.emf.ecore-2.15.0.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
     for more information

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have no idea how to solve it. I was trying refresh cache, changing repository, no luck. This two cache directories are created at same time. Adding  packagingOptions not helped...